# Не могу импортировать базу на другой сервер

Tags: mysql

пробовал через phpmyadmin сохранить дамп, но при загрузке дампа выдает ошибку:
`#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе.`
попробовал через ssh загрузить, там уже выдало ошибку:
`ERROR at line 189356: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected`
попробовал с --binary-mode:
`ERROR at line 189356: Unknown command '\\'.`
Решил сохранить дамп через mysqldump и это помогло! Базу получилось загрузить в итоге на другой сервер, но почему то в одной таблице вместо ~400к записей стало ~600к

Дамп весит: 101.3 mb
Различие между серверами только в версии ubuntu, остальное все тоже самое.
8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1(делал дамп), 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 (сюда импортировал ее).
Кодировка одна и та же, у файла кодировка utf-8, смотрел через ssh `file dump.sql`

Как быть?

Comment: *почему то в одной таблице вместо ~400к записей стало ~600к* А Вы почистили БД после первой, неудачной, попытки импорта?

Comment: да, я в другую даже попробовал рядом и на сервер откуда ее дампил, теперь еще этот сервер упал...
Да и остальные таблицы имеют нужное количество записей. Только одна таблица разбухла почти в 2 раза.

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Если в таблице и правда 400к записей, то и в дамп должно попасть 400к строк. Проверьте, сколько их там реально. Кстати, а в системе не используется ли "мягкое" удаление? Ну и если в дампе вставляется 400к строк, то столько и вставится. Ну ещё посмотрите на триггеры - нет ли таких, что вставляют записи в проблемную таблицу при операциях на других таблицах? Триггеры, констрейнты и прочие такого рода вещи должны создаваться после заливки данных - посмотрите дамп, нет ли там с порядком операций какого косяка?

Comment: Я вас понимаю, но вот я этот же дамп попытался развернуть на сервере откуда взял его и там уже 200к строк стало в таблице. И почему-то только с 1 таблицей такая магия происходит. 
Сервер упал из-за нехваатки памяти на диске. Почистил немного, вроде заработал. Может в этом проблема? Ну с 200к строками еще можно понять, но как это отражается на другом сервере.

Comment: @Akina , ну я же не слепой. В базе таблица с 400к+ строк > дамплю > импортирую на другом сервере > 600к+ строк, глянул руками одну запись по поиску, она записалась х3 раза почему то. 
В базе даже внешних ключей не было...
Вот цифры точные с таблицы где делал дамп: ~444 808 , куда экспортировал: 640 186
Причем кстати в phpmyadmin прям так и написано с знаком "~"
А это не может быть из-за проблем с памятью?